# How to put an image on another

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>

  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-xrRywqdh3PHs8keKZN+8zzc5TX0GRTLCcmivcbNJWm2rs5C8PRhcEn3czEjhAO9o" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <style>
    .page {
      /*width: 58.3396%; 
        height: 16.914%;*/
      width: 30%;
      height: 5%;
      transform: matrix3d(0.93, 0.36, 0.00, 0, -0.36, 0.93, 0.00, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
      -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.93, 0.36, 0.00, 0, -0.36, 0.93, 0.00, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <img src="./img/background.jpg" class="img-fluid">
    <img src="./img/img1.jpeg" class="page">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

How to put a picture on the green and blue background? Is it possible to use only css for this purpose, for example with the 3d transform functions?

Comment: please add 2 images here

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You need to provide more informations, where will this be used? is this a homepage? in which elements u intend to use it? (div, p), provide some website structure where u intend to use it. Also have it to be responsive?

Comment: I want put an image (responsive or not) above green and blue background without animations.

Answer (score 2):

## Update

You can do it like this:

Use the `matrix3d` `transform`:

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
div img {
  width: 100%;
}
div span:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/375/151?image=990) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 375px;
  height: 151px;
  transform: matrix3d( 0.548752   ,  0.14839    , 0, -0.000261138, 
                      -0.533756   ,  0.203838   , 0, -0.000359532, 
                       0          ,  0          , 1,  0          ,
                      91          , 95          , 0, 1
  );
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
div span:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/240/200?image=991) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 240px;
  height: 200px;
  transform: matrix3d( 0.320781, 0.0786819, 0, -0.000358941, 
                      -0.236755, 0.3753   , 0, -0.000196034, 
                       0       , 0        , 1, 0, 
                     252       , 46       , 0, 1
  );
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppZGY.jpg" alt="" />
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

The matrix elements are derived using this tool https://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/Lbgr63s5/14/ which is a copy with some changes from here http://jsfiddle.net/dFrHS/1/ which is described in this SE answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/339033/65531

## Old

It can be doable. But I don't know how this can be easily done.

Right here I have an example which does not fit 100 per cent but you should see the method.

You have to play with `perspective` and `perspective-origin` on the `div` and with `top`, `left`, `transform`, `width` and `height` on the `span`to get it right.

You see I didn't quite get it correct. Those values are highly yielded by experiment and I can't tell, how you would get them exactly.

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
  perspective-origin: -533px -361px;
}

div img {
  width: 100%;
}

div span:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/175/151?image=990) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  width: 175px;
  height: 151px;
  top: 96.3px;
  left: 91px;
  transform: rotateX(93deg) rotateY(362deg) rotateZ(53deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppZGY.jpg" alt="" />
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: @DiegoMiranda I made some approvements to my answer

Comment: any idea how to put it in responsive mode?

Comment: @DiogoMiranda I have no idea

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using only CSS, but like mentioned above making it responsive and such could become a bit tricker.

So I'll assume it can be a static width, in which case you could do something like:

- Add the background-image (with the blue/green blocks) to an element (DIV or something)
- Either use it's psuedo elements (`::before` and `::after`) **or** add two child elements (could also be div's) to hold the other images
- Position both child elements individually using `position:absolute; left: FOO; top: BAR;` (don't forget to set `position: relative;` on the parent div
- Use something like: `transform: scale(1) skew(15deg)` or transform 3D options to skew / distort it so it matches the 3D plane

**TL;DR**

- Attach bg image
- Create two elements to hold other images
- Position each one absolutely to match position
- Add transform(s) to match orientation
- Profit :)

Note: if using the pseudo classes don't forget to set `content: ""` or attach the image there. Psuedo's will not be visible otherwise

Transform info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform

Pseudos: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements